# regex replace in dreamweaver

Tags: regex, dreamweaver

I'm trying to replace tags in my code, but keeping the text inside "as is".
example string:

```
<p class="negrita">text1</p>
```

or

```
<p class="negrita">text2</p>
```

i need to get those replaced as so:

```
<h3>text1</h3>
```

and

```
<h3>text2</h3>
```

i'm searching (and matching fine) with this,

```
<p class="negrita">([^>]*)</p>
```

but I have no idea on how to keep the text inside, as

```
<h3>$1</h3>
```

is not working.

Comment: in which language are you executing the regex. This `$1` should work...

Comment: How is it not working? What do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using regular expressions to do this, use Dreamweaver's Specific Tag search option.  While regular expressions are possible in Dreamweaver, it's a bit crippled and sometimes a little buggy.

To do this with Specific Tag, invoke the search using Control-F

1. Change the search option to "Specific Tag".
2. Next to that, enter p to search for all `<p>` tags
3. Hit the + icon below the box to add an option and select "With Attribute" "Class" "=" from the first three pulldowns and type "negrita" in the fourth.
4. For action, select "Change Tag" and then select h3.

Run this and you will get `<h3 class="negrita">text1</h3>`

Then repeat the steps above, searching for all h3 tags with the class negrita and choose Remove Attribute "class" for the action.  Two steps to one, I admit but it will work every time.